Graffiti on the Moon
A common plot in child-friendly superhero stories is for a villain to try to deface an important landmark or monument. In the case of terrestrial places, the legal status of such an act is pretty cut-and-dried.
However, what if someone defaces an extraterrestrial landmark (such as by etching his or her visage into the Moon using a giant laser)? What laws would apply (if it would even be illegal in the first place)?

A reading of Clarke's "Watch this space", https://archive.org/details/Fantasy_Science_Fiction_v012n02_1957-02_PDF/page/n79/mode/2up?view=theater is indicated...

Both the Outer Space Treaty (1967) and the Moon Treaty (1984) state that the Moon and its resources cannot be claimed by any nation. The first has been ratified by all major spacefaring nations, but the second has not.
So if you deface the Moon, there is no state which can bring charges for the damage.
However, there is no laser that exists today with enough power to do what you suggest. And when there is, Article IX of the Outer Space Treaty says:

States must avoid harmful contamination and adverse changes to the space environment, including the Moon.

So the state in which the laser is situated might bring charges against the individual, for violating the Treaty. Moreover such a powerful laser could be seen as a weapon of mass destruction, which itself is subject to regulation.

The treaties place obligations on states, not individuals. Charges cannot be brought against an individual for violating the treaty, only against the individual for violating the laws of a signatory state that it might adopt in an effort to enforce the treaty, but probably hasn't so far.

The heat output just to create the laser should vaporazie a part of the neighborhood where it is fired...

@Trish It was just an example, there may be other ways to deface the moon.

@ohwilleke in the 90s when advertising on the moon was purposed the idea was that would stop them, irl.

This seems to misquote Article IX - it says that states must "avoid [celestial bodies'] harmful contamination and also adverse changes in the environment of the Earth resulting from the introduction of extraterrestrial matter..." (emphasis mine, referring to earth and not space environments). I don't think Article IX applies here at all, a laser wouldn't contaminate the moon, nor introduce extraterrestrial matter to earth. I'm not sure that laser etching necessarily classes as "harmful contamination" of the moon.

@NuclearHoagie, it says "including the Moon", and etching it might well be considered an "adverse change". It depends if the graffito is big and bold enough to be seen – if not, what's the point? It's unwelcome in my street, IMO on the Moon too.

@WeatherVane The part about "adverse changes" applies to the environment of earth, Article IX doesn't say anything about adverse changes to other celestial bodies. It just says we can't contaminate them - "States Parties to the Treaty shall pursue studies of outer space, including the moon and other celestial bodies, and conduct exploration of them so as to avoid their harmful contamination and also adverse changes in the environment of the Earth resulting from the introduction of extraterrestrial matter..."

Nothing in this answer prevents a country from passing a law under which it can prosecute one of its citizens or residents for defacing the moon.

@JBentley I don't think any answer would prevent new laws being passed. What's your point?

My point is that the following assertion is wrong: " there is no state which can bring charges for the damage." You're relying on the treaty as preventing states from doing this, but the treaty doesn't have that effect.
